# Find combinations in choose(k, n) in a R loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, statistics

I need to find the SUM of all possible combinations in a set. For example:

```
sum(choose(5, 0),

    choose(5, 1),

    choose(5, 2),

    choose(5, 3),

    choose(5, 4),

    choose(5, 5))
```

Instead of writing it out like that, is possible to use a for loop to loop through `choose()` with any given `n` and `k`?

Comment: `choose()` is vectorised so you can just do `sum(choose(5, 0:5))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want to do this for more than just one `n` you can use `sapply`

```
setNames( sapply( 1:10, function(x) sum( choose( x, 0:x ) ) ), 1:10 )
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
   2    4    8   16   32   64  128  256  512 1024
```

Or using a `for` loop

```
res <- vector(l=10)
for(i in 1:10){ res[i] <- sum( choose( i, 0:i ) ) }
res
 [1]    2    4    8   16   32   64  128  256  512 1024
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
> sum(choose(5, 0:5))
[1] 32
```

or just apply the [binomial sums](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialSums.html)

```
> 2^5
[1] 32
```